# Help with PHP Array code

Tags: php, arrays

Hey guys!
I need some help writing a code that creates an array in the format I needed in.  I have this long string of text like this -> "settings=2&options=3&color=3&action=save"...etc  Now the next thing I did to make it into an array is the following:

```
$form_data = explode("&", $form_data);
```

Ok so far so good...I now have an array like so:

```
Array
(
[0] => settings=2
[1] => options=3
[2] => color=3
[3] => action=save
)
1
```

Ok now I need to know how to do two things.  First, how can I remove all occurences of "action=save" from the array?

Second, how can I make this array become a key value pair (associative array)?  Like "settings=>2"?

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [a function](http://php.net/parse_str) for that. :)

```
parse_str('settings=2&options=3&color=3&action=save', $arr);
if (isset($arr['action']) && $arr['action'] == 'save') {
    unset($arr['action']);
}
print_r($arr);
```

But just for reference, you could do it manually like this:

```
$str = 'settings=2&options=3&color=3&action=save';
$arr = array();
foreach (explode('&', $str) as $part) {
    list($key, $value) = explode('=', $part, 2);
    if ($key == 'action' && $value == 'save') {
        continue;
    }
    $arr[$key] = $value;
}
```

This is not quite equivalent to `parse_str`, since `key[]` keys wouldn't be parsed correctly. I'd be sufficient for your example though.

Comment: thanks for the help however I have one question. While trying your code, it seems it does not process duplicates.  For example I have "action=2&settings=3&action=2"..etc.  As you can see in the string, there is "action=2" two times. But using the code you had before you added the condition to remove them shows an array but with only one instance of the action=save.  Is that true? Or is there a way to keep the duplicates?

Comment: @Rick Well, *how* would you want to keep them? You can't keep both as keys. Usually only the last one sticks. If you parse it manually, you can do something else with it: `if (isset($arr[$key])) { /* key already exists, do something about it */ }`.

Comment: ahhhh, so I am guessing there CANNOT be duplicate of same name keys in the array, that is why?

Comment: @Rick Yes, *keys* are unique. Otherwise which value would you get when accessing `$arr['action']`?

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 'settings=2&options=3&color=3&action=save&action=foo&bar=save';
parse_str($str, $array);
$key = array_search('save', $array);
if($key == 'action') {
        unset($array['action']);
}
```

[Ideone Link](http://www.ideone.com/w0Bf2)

Comment: ok I am not fully understanding..are you just implying I should use parse_str to make the string into an array?  But the way I did it, is exactly what I need which is to remove the "&".  Also, did you read the rest of my question on how to do the additional two things?

Answer (score 0):

This could help on the parsing your array, into key/values

```
$array; // your array here
$new_array = array();

foreach($array as $key)
{
    $val = explode('=',$key);
    // could also unset($array['action']) if that's a global index you want removed
    // if so, no need to use the if/statement below - 
    // just the setting of the new_array  
    if(($val[0] != 'action' && $val[1] != 'save'))$new_array[] = array($val[0]=>$val[1]);
}
```